How to efficiently read values of points from COG / STAC
I am trying to read the values of 40.000 points from a STAC catalog that covers 6 years, for all dates available in the catalog. I am expecting around 17520000 values in total. The STAC catalog stores data as COG files. What would be the most efficient way to get all the values of these points for the whole time span of the catalog?
I have tried using odc.stac with dask but it seems that something is keeping every downloaded COG internal tile in RAM even though only a couple of pixels are useful from each internal tile. This results in RAM exploding as it takes almost 1 GB of RAM per date.
I think the main problem is downloading values for the relevant pixels instead of the whole internal tile, or discarding non-relevant pixels as soon as the relevant ones are extracted from the internal tile.

You could use rasterio's DatasetReader.sample() method, e.g.:
import geopandas as gpd
import planetary_computer
from pystac_client import Client
import rasterio as rio
from shapely.geometry import box

stac = "https://planetarycomputer.microsoft.com/api/stac/v1"
collection = "sentinel-2-l2a"
points = gpd.read_file("points.geojson")
bands = ["B04", "B08"]

geom = box(*points.geometry.total_bounds)
client = Client.open(stac, modifier=planetary_computer.sign_inplace)

search = client.search(
    max_items=25,
    collections="sentinel-2-l2a",
    intersects=geom,
)

with rio.Env(GDAL_DISABLE_READDIR_ON_OPEN="EMPTY_DIR"):
    for item in (search.items_as_dicts()):
        dt = item["properties"]["datetime"]
        geometry = points.geometry.to_crs(item["properties"]["proj:epsg"])
        data = {"timestamp": [dt] * len(geometry)}
        for b in bands:
            with rio.open(item["assets"][b]["href"]) as ds:
                data[b] = (value[0] for value in ds.sample(zip(points.geometry.x, points.geometry.y)))
                # do something with data...

